# Backbone.js Model::set custom comparison

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

An underscore _.isEqual call is used to determine whether a model's attributes changed in Backbone.Model::set.  _.isEqual will perform a deep comparison on objects by default, but we intend on storing complex objects in the attributes, other Backbone Models for instance.  A deep check between Models will always fail as there's differences in the internal ids, etc...

In this case it'd be helpful if a custom comparator could be defined.  For instance if I want to compare just the attributes of sub models rather than all of their properties, I could make a "compare" static method for the base object and Backbone.set would pass that to _.isEqual.

Is there a way to handle this case?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20352846/change-event-triggering-on-momentjs-object/20356272#20356272 , but that implies you're ok with overriding `model.set`

Comment: Good link, and we're moving down that path, but hoping there's a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply overwrite the comparison method for your App

Comment: Overwrite Backbone.Model::set and/or _.isEqual?  The team is progressing down that path, but my concern is that we'll have to keep writing patches whenever Backbone updates. It's a heavy method, and there's not too many places to insert this kind of tweak